# Get PDO connection stats

Tags: php, pdo

Using PHP, When using the mysqli library, there are certain stats available, as seen here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php

Are there any such stats available when using the PDO library? I'm trying to find the best way to get the total bytes transferred to log after script end.

Comment: I think you can get a lot of stats from MySQL itself. Through [SHOW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show.html), which is [explained here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mysql-performance-metrics/). There will be overlap, but it depends on what stats you're interested in if this is helpful or not.

Comment: PDO (PHP Data Objects) doesn't provide a direct function like mysqli_get_connection_stats to obtain connection statistics, including the total bytes transferred, as it does with MySQLi. PDO is a more abstract and general-purpose database abstraction layer, and it doesn't expose the same level of low-level details as MySQLi.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can still use MySQLi stats methods to display stats about PDO calls, as long as both are using mysqlnd, which is probably the case unless the PHP installation is a bit old ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php)). Of course, it isn't ideal as it adds a new dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I need from this query after everything is done:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE "Bytes_received"
```

Not the most ideal, but I believe that's the best I'm going to get using PDO.